# Eigenvalues and Eigenfunctions for Homogenous Two Point Boundary Value Problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

> Find the eigenvalues and Eigen functions for homogenous two point boundary value problem

$$u''+\lambda u =0$$$$u'(0)=u'(1)=0$$$$\lambda> 0,u=A\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x+B\sin \sqrt{\lambda}x,$$$$B=0,\sqrt{\lambda}=n\pi,\lambda=n^2\pi^2$$$$cos{n{\pi}x}$$$$\lambda=0,u=A+Bx, B=0$$$$\lambda< 0,$$

> not an eigenvalue:

$$u=Ae^{x\sqrt{-\lambda}}-Be^{-x{\sqrt{-\lambda}}},$$$$A=B=0$$

> But where to from here?

Comment: That $A=B=0$ case also can't be an eigenvalue. But past that point you are done.

Comment: I can't tell if you realize that for the $\lambda = 0$ case, $1$ is an eigenfunction.  The complete set of eigenvalue/eigenfunction pairs is $(n^2\pi^2, \cos(n\pi x))$ for $n=0, 1, 2, \ldots.$

Comment: @B.Goddard I think liana1000 noticed that (they pointed out $B=0$ there but didn't say anything about $A$).